# Will bridging the collector and emitter of a transistor damage it?

Tags: transistors

I have an inverter which uses a thermistor and a transistor to control the fan. The problem is that the thermistor temp is set so high that even when the inverter (transformer) is fairly hot the fan doesn't turn on but only turns on very high loads.

What I am trying to do is to add a resistor between the fan controlling transistor's collector and emitter so that the fan runs in slow mode even when the transistor is not emitting.

Will it damage the transistor if I bridge the emitter and collector?  Will the transistor still work in the circuit?

Comment: I'm no thermistor expert but wouldn't you be better off putting a resistor in parallel with the thermistor so it always thinks it is a bit hotter than it is? Use a pot so you can adjust

Comment: Only when we see the schematic can we judge if your proposal is OK or not. So include the schematic. If you bridge the collector and emitter then you effectively bypass the transistor so it will not be doing anything. It is like when you short the contacts of a switch, then the switch doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: Assuming a _typical_ fan control circuit, shorting the Emitter to the Collector won't hurt it. But we don't know what circuit your unit has. Please trace the circuit around the transistor and show it to us.

Comment: How have you concluded that the thermistor temperature is set high ? IMHO, the thermistor itself doesn't have a *set temperature*. The voltage across or current through the thermistor is probably compared to a reference. It might be that a component setting this reference has failed. If so, you might be better off replacing that component.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the transistor is probably operating in common emitter mode that will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Bridging the emitter and collector will just create a free path for charge carriers to flow.

N type doped regions and P type doped regions by themselves act like conductors.  N-N junctions act like conductors (same amount of doping) and P-P junctions act like conductors(same amount of doping).